# spring beanpostprocessor doesn't work on component-scan?

Tags: java, spring

I have many cookie-cutter spring beans and don't want to explicitly define each one in xml.  So I went the component scanning route which lets me do this.  This is nice, but I just realized that MyBeanPostProcessor isn't being called for the beans loaded in using the component-scan technique.  MyBeanPostProcessor simply attempts to do some setter injection on these beans.  The below configuration just shows this approach I tried which doesn't work.  Any other ideas how to do setter injection on these beans?

I'm using **Spring 2.5.5**

Thanks,
Ben

```
<context:component-scan base-package="us.benanderson" 
        use-default-filters="false" 
        annotation-config="false"
        scope-resolver="us.benanderson.MyScopeResolver"
        name-generator="us.benanderson.MyBeanNameGenerator">
    <context:include-filter type="custom" expression="us.benanderson.MyTypeFilter" />
</context:component-scan>
<bean class="us.benanderson.MyBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="order" value="500" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What happens if you try explicitly adding a bean definition instead of using classpath scanning? Can you confirm that the post processor works in that case?

Comment: yes, I did confirm that the beanpostprocessor works in that case

Comment: are you looking for alternatives to the BeanPostProcessor for injection? Or is your primary goal to get component-scan working with or without the BeanPostProcessor?

Comment: alternatives would be fine, although I'm not sure there are any.
My requirement is:
 - auto load beans w/out needing to explicitly define them
 - do some simple setter injection
"MyBeanPostProcessor isn't being called for the beans loaded in using the component-scan technique."
I don't really know how else to say this.  The beans that are defined using the component-scan technique aren't being passed to MyBeanPostProcessor.  MyBeanPostProcessor simply is attempting to do some setter injection.  MyBeanPostProcessor works fine for beans that I explicitly define in the xml.

Comment: I created a small test case and it works perfectly for me. Even when I have annotation-config turned off and am using a custom TypeFilter. I think your best option is to try and take a few steps back: try to isolate the problem. I see you have your own scope resolver - this could be the culprit (not that it SHOULD cause a problem - it's a possibility though).

Comment: waxwing,
thanks for the info.  geez, I isolated the issue as far as I could.  No - I didn't try every combination possible, but I guess it's worth a shot since you said it works for you.  What version of spring are you using?

but there's no other way to set the scope than with a custom scope resolver is there?  So unless I'm happy with the default (singleton) scope, then I need the scope resolver, right?

Comment: I used Spring 2.5.6 for my tests. If you are interested I'd be willing to post my code. Maybe it will help, or it you will be able to find that I did something fundamentally different that won't work in your case. (Or that I misunderstood the problem completely!)

Comment: sure - post it - I'll vote it up if you do.  I doubt there's much variation from what I did because I don't think there's many different possibilities, but who knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my test case, that appears to work (Spring 2.5.6). I thought about excluding some files for brevity, but I decided against it.

Start.java (entry-point)

```
package se.waxwing.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("se/waxwing/test/Context.xml");
        context.getBean("customBean");
    }
}
```

Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="se.waxwing.test" 
        use-default-filters="false" 
        annotation-config="false"
        scope-resolver="se.waxwing.test.MyScopeResolver">
        <context:include-filter type="custom" expression="se.waxwing.test.MyTypeFilter" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="beanProcessor" class="se.waxwing.test.MyBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

CustomBean.java (this is the I want to find - see MyTypeFilter)

```
package se.waxwing.test;

public class CustomBean {

    public CustomBean() {
        System.err.println("instantiating component");
    }
}
```

MyBeanPostProcessor.java

```
package se.waxwing.test;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public MyBeanPostProcessor() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        System.err.println("after " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        System.err.println("before " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }   
}
```

MyScopeResolver.java

```
package se.waxwing.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopeMetadata;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopeMetadataResolver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;

public class MyScopeResolver implements ScopeMetadataResolver {

    @Override
    public ScopeMetadata resolveScopeMetadata(BeanDefinition definition) {
        ScopeMetadata result = new ScopeMetadata();
        result.setScopedProxyMode(ScopedProxyMode.NO);
        result.setScopeName("prototype");
        return result;
    }

}
```

MyTypeFilter.java

```
package se.waxwing.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MetadataReader;
import org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MetadataReaderFactory;
import org.springframework.core.type.filter.TypeFilter;

public class MyTypeFilter implements TypeFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) throws IOException {
        return metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName().equals(CustomBean.class.getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
2009-aug-26 15:44:02 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@c1b531: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@c1b531]; startup date [Wed Aug 26 15:44:02 CEST 2009]; root of context hierarchy
2009-aug-26 15:44:02 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [se/waxwing/test/Context.xml]
2009-aug-26 15:44:02 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@c1b531]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@121f1d
2009-aug-26 15:44:02 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@121f1d: defining beans [customBean,beanProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
instantiating component
before customBean
after customBean
```

So, as you can see, the `customBean` bean was found by my type filter, added as a bean, and when `applicationContext.getBean("customBean")` was called a new object was instantiated and then it was passed to my post bean processor.

Comment: I'm an idiot!  After I downloaded spring 2.5.6 and tried it out (and it was still broken), I noticed the fact that I wasn't calling applicationContext.getBean("customBean")!  So it was actually working for me all along - just my way of confirming it was broken!  Thanks for submitting your code and confirming that it works.  I want to give you the bounty, but I don't know how.  There's no check box or anything - according to this:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13421/cant-accept-answer-for-bountied-question-on-serverfault
I guess you're out of luck?

Comment: No problem, it got me to play around with custom scope-resolvers and type-filters, which is a good thing. Guess I am out of luck on that bounty - can't fight the system. :)

Answer (score -1):

After the application context has loaded check that the beans that you've annotated are available.

I suspect since you've turned off "annotation-config" that it is ignoring your annotations.

Comment: yes, I have verified that the beans are available.  I wrote my own Filter which is why I turned off annotation-config.